# Inner join with system tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have these two queries, I need to do an inner join but I don't know which field to relate them to

```
SELECT * from Information_Schema.Tables where TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE name LIKE '%Log%'
GO
```

or how else could you relate the tables to the triggers and be able to get fields from both?

Comment: Don't use `Information_Schema.Tables` use `sys.tables` and then you can `JOIN` on `object_id`.

Comment: Oh embarrassed thank you friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.triggers` joins to `sys.tables` on `sys.triggers.parent_id`, eg

```
select t.name, trig.name trigger_name
from sys.tables t
join sys.triggers trig
  on trig.parent_class = 1
 and trig.parent_id = t.object_id
```